# ASP.NET serving both desktop and mobile static files

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-files, kestrel-http-server

I have two sets of static files to serve for a website - one for a desktop website, and one for mobile. I'm currently serving just the desktop files from a Kestrel server:

```
public void Run()
{
    host = new WebHostBuilder()
          .UseKestrel()
          .UseWebRoot(serverConfig.WebRoot)
          // More config stuff... 
          .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .Build();

    host.RunAsync();
}
```

Where the directory of the files is `serverConfig.WebRoot`.

Is there a way of also serving the mobile static files - presumably from the same WebRoot directory - depending on the type of request the server receives? I.e. if from a desktop, serve desktop files; if from a mobile, serve mobile files. I'm sure that it's pretty obvious (from a) the fact that I'm asking this question, and b) my phrasing) that I'm pretty new to ASP.NET & Kestrel, but I hope I've given enough information.

I've had a look at the Kestrel documentation, and haven't managed to find anything relevant. It's also been suggested that I write my own file server, but, since my knowledge of anything web-related is pretty close to 0, I thought it might be worth trying this first.

Comment: Is there a reason to not put both desktop and mobile static files in the same directory? Choosing mobile or desktop resources should be done in the [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2) or [layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Or even better, use the same resources and something like [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: @Stijn Thanks for the reply! :) No, not at all. I would assume that both sets of static files should exist in the same root directory, but I'm just not sure how to serve the necessary files depending on the request. Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the front-end, just the Kestrel server.

Comment: That's going to be difficult, if not impossible. `UseWebRoot` simply sets a configuration parameter that can then be consumed by another module. You *might* be able to intercept requests somehow with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2#manage-the-host), but I'm not familiar with that area so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Stijn I see. I'll take a look into that! Thanks for taking the time to help. 

Obviously won't ask for details here, but would writing my own file server be a massive task? One of my colleagues has written something similar in Kotlin, but not sure how it'd translate.

Comment: No idea, sorry. If you can get access to the `IApplicationBuilder` (e.g. in Startup.cs `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime, IHostingEnvironment env)`) then you can simply inject custom middleware, but I think at `IWebHostBuilder` level this is not possible. Someone else can hopefully confirm or refute this.

Comment: @Stijn I have access to that, so I guess - for now, at least - I'll look into writing my own middleware.